# don't show video in photo library in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios5, photo-gallery

All I want is to show the selection of photos only in MediaLibrary of iPhone via Application.

I don't want the user to see videos to select from there.

What can be the way(chance) of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html):

```
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes = 
    [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to show MediaLibrary.

```
imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
```

It'll show you only images of media library.

Comment: If videos are captured using device camera, then they will be added to PhotoLibrary. The code you  provided opens the PhotoLibrary in which Videos are also included.

Comment: then change the source type to :UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum It'll work....

Comment: From the Link:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html  -- "`UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`
Specifies the device’s Camera Roll album as the source for the image picker controller. If the device does not have a camera, specifies the Saved Photos album as the source."

Comment: So basically your requirement is fulfilled by this source type. And if the device does not have a camera and you want user to restrict to select image then also you can change it.... let me know if you face any problem....